# Xcode project file size is rather large

Tags: xcode, macos, finder

Ok, so I am close to submitting my WWDC scholarship app, however I have just noticed that the file size for my Xcode project is 130mb. The limit is 100mb.

When I click 'get info' on the project folder in the 'Developer' folder, it tells me that it's 130mb, but then if I go into that folder and check the three folders sizes, one is 53mb and the other two are tiny... So why is it telling me that it's 130mb overall?

Also, I've just checked it again and without changing anything, it's gone up to 132mb?!

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like you might be putting your derived data somewhere within your Source or Project folder instead of the Xcode default locations (which are hiding in "`~/Library/Developer`").  Do things change in terms of size when you do a clean?  Also, what makes your app so big to begin with?  Sound files or images or?

Comment: No difference when I performed a clean. There is 52mb worth of images. Would I be able to compress them enough to get the file size below 100mb?

Comment: If they are png images you might be able to reduce the image size dramatically with [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com)

Comment: Ok. I'll give that a try. Any other suggestions if that doesn't quite get it under 100mb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce Xcode project file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879093/how-to-reduce-xcode-project-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is using any video files to be displayed for the user, then you can place them in the server and download it on request and cache them. For one of our project i have followed this approach and it tried to save space.