# How to reduce Xcode project file size

Tags: xcode, macos, finder

So I am trying to submit my WWDC scholarship app, however the file size limit is 100mb, and mine is currently 132mb. I have spent the past few hours reducing the size of the images, and compressing them, but I only saved about 10mb...

So now I am trying to figure out what is taking up all of the space, and what I can delete to get it under 100mb.

I noticed that when I go into the 'Developer' folder and right click on my project and tap 'Get info', it shows that the file is 132mb, however if I go in and check the three folders individually they only add up to about 40mb.

If I go to `~/Library/Developer/DerivedData` then the file for this project is about 250mb, so is there something in there that can be deleted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isn't this the same question as one [you asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874245/xcode-project-file-size-is-rather-large)?

Comment: Similar, but I added more information. I was pretty desperate for a solution quickly though and hopefully you can understand, given that I've worked on this app non-stop for the past two weeks and it was looking like I wasn't going to be able to submit it. Thankfully I've just fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I used the terminal command to uncover hidden files, and found that there was a .git file in the folder which was taking up 93mb. I have now deleted the file and it brought down the size to 37mb.

Answer (score 0):

`~/Library/Developer/DerivedData` can be deleted in its entirety at any time. However, doing so will not affect the size of the app.

Looks first at any assets that you have included, images, videos, sounds, data, and fonts. Figure out what can be eliminated, reduced, or hosted externally. Many times you can replace large images with drawing code.

Comment: I only have 35mb of images, and 1 font file, so there must be something else taking up the space. Is there nothing worth checking for that could be deleted?

Comment: Ok, I've discovered (by uncovering the hidden files) that there is a git file that takes up 93mb? Can I remove this or reduce it's size?

Answer (score 0):

Select your project target > Build Settings, check your `VALID_ARCHS`:

[image]

Remove useless ones, only keep right & less archs for your project, more archs will lead the final archived binary bigger. I think you can only keep `x86_64` there in this case.

---

More reading about the `ARCH`, you can take a look at [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x/22394605#22394605) (it's about iOS).